# Be able to edit the text of a <p> on click and change the original value

Tags: jquery, html, textinput

Is there a way to be able to edit the text in a `<p>` element when you click it, like make it a  text input when you click on it, I can kind of manage this on my own, but would like to know a simple, easy way to do it.

However, the hard part is that I would like it to change the actual `<p>` contents when you press enter, or click out of the text input.

Thanks, I have tried to explain this as well as possible.

Comment: How do you want to edit it? In place, in a popup dialog?

Comment: You might want to look at using a plugin like:
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use HTML5 you can add the attribute contenteditable="true"

if you don't want to use HTML5 here is jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/uGU6p/

Comment: Oh that's awesome! You can even do ctrl-i/b/etc to change font style.

Comment: yes, contenteditable allows for rich textareas, but be careful because it is only compatible with recent browsers

Comment: The support seems quite decent anyway, at least according to this source: http://caniuse.com/contenteditable

Answer (score 0):

You could to use some sort of inline editing plugin.   I found this:

http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick go at rolling my own. It definitely needs some touch ups, but the concepts seem good.

**Version 2**

http://jsfiddle.net/jRtr3/1

```
//track the active editable area
var activep;

//when p is clicked place an editable text area over it
$('p').click( function () {
    activep = $(this);       
    $('<input class="editable" />')
    .appendTo('body')
    .focus()
    .val($(this).text())
    .css('top', $(this).position().top)
    .css('left', $(this).position().left)
    .width($(this).width())
    .height($(this).height() + 20);
});

//when exiting editable text area, replace its corresponding p tag with new value
$('.editable').live('blur', function () {
    $(activep).text($(this).val());
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: V2 - Made an update to use textareas instead of inputs. Remove instead of hide old elements. Make cursor appear at end of text area instead of beginning.